# Creating a Full Text Index search

Tags: mysql, search, full-text-search, full-text-indexing

I've created a blog and I wish to search through certain tables in my MySQL databases and then return results for the user on a separate search page. I do not wish to use Google CSE. How would I go about creating this for my site. I found a post on StackOverflow.com from a friend of mine in which he wished to make his more efficient. How would I go about implementing his search engine into my site?

His Code - [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2954022/mysql-php-search-efficiency)

Answer (score 0):

Are you limited to SQL? There is a lot of software better suitable for text search than any relational database engine. Sphinx, Lucene, Xapian, just to name few.

**EDIT**
MySQL has some full-text indexing capabilities as well. [You may want to check them out](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html).