# Add FullText Capability to existing table in MySql

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, full-text-indexing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MySQL/PHP Search Efficiency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2954022/mysql-php-search-efficiency)

How to Add FullText Capability to the existing table in MySQL.

I've seen adding it directly at the time of table creation as follow.

```
CREATE TABLE articles (
    id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    title VARCHAR(200),
    body TEXT,
    FULLTEXT (title,body)
);
```

But how to add FullText Manually after the table is created?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the docs at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/alter-table.html

`ALTER TABLE TABLE_NAME ADD [FULLTEXT|SPATIAL] [INDEX|KEY] [index_name]`

Comment: Note you'll need to add the attributes you want full text on in first!

Comment: is it  correct? ALTER TABLE articles ADD [FULLTEXT] [INDEX] [Title]

Comment: Thanks for your effort @SiGanteng
I got better answer from here.http://stackoverflow.com/a/2954062/1518640

Comment: @hungrycoder no problem, also, make sure that your table is using MyISAM as its engine.

Comment: yes it is using MyISAM only. But only problem is I need to check whether the FullText Catalog is supported by my hosting provider or not.